# How to get data from strapi endpoints it shows 404 error?

Tags: strapi

http://localhost:1337/api/category/

When I use this endpoint it shows a 404 not found error in postman.

```
{"data":null,"error":{"status":404,"name":"NotFoundError","message":"Not Found","details":{}}}
```

I gave access to the public but it's not working.

[image]

What should I do now to get the API data?

Comment: Did you have published record in category content manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error 404 means that there's no endpoint for the requested URL.

Strapi uses a plural collection name for its endpoint. So, in your case, the endpoint should be `http://localhost:1337/api/categories`. This rule applies to all "core" endpoints generated by Strapi.

Check out this documentation to learn more: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest#endpoints

Hope that helps!